# Shows connection is closed even if connection.open is present - Works when I remove Try Block

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

This is the function to access the database; the connection string is perfect - There is another Function similar to this and it works fine.

```
Friend Shared Function AddMember(member As Object) As Task(Of Integer)
    Dim connection = New SqlConnection(Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Carrel").ConnectionString)
     Dim query = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO JSON (CATEGORY,DATA) VALUES ('MEM',@JSONString)", connection)
        Try
            Connection.Open()
            query.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@JSONString", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(member)))
            Return query.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString())
            Throw
        Finally
            query.Connection.Close()
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: Where it shows connection is closed?

Comment: Are you accidentally calling Connection.Open(), not connection.Open() (notice the casing!)

Comment: The place where I call this function

Comment: No, the casing doesn't effect.

Comment: Are you sure? VB.Net allows mixing case-- it's not case sensitive. But it is _case aware_, and Visual Studio will normally correct a name that differs only by case from the declaration... _unless you have two names that differ only by case_, such as a variable name and a type name that are the same, or a local variable and a member variable that are the same. That Visual Studio did not auto-correct `Connection` to `connection` is an indication you may have a naming conflict.

Comment: i changed still not working

Comment: [this](https://github.com/Prathik-Jain/Carrel-LibraryManagmentSystem/blob/fd3208d5a3e8910fcf162da6133fd009d265ce4b/LibraryManagement/MemberForm.xaml.vb#L37) is where the function is called and [this](https://github.com/Prathik-Jain/Carrel-LibraryManagmentSystem/blob/fd3208d5a3e8910fcf162da6133fd009d265ce4b/LibraryManagement/Sevices/MemberService.vb#L6) is the function itself

Comment: Title - @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: Title @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: You need to do "connection.Close" in stead of "query.Connection.Close()"

Comment: I dont know VB but I would make sure the connection object and the query object are disposed after using them. in c# that would be "using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("")) { your code here }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Friend Shared Async Function AddMember(member As Object) As Task(Of Integer)
    Dim cn AS New SqlConnection(Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Carrel").ConnectionString)
    Dim query As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO JSON (CATEGORY,DATA) VALUES ('MEM',@JSONString)", cn)
    Try
        cn.Open()
        query.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@JSONString", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(member)))
        Return Await query.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
        Throw
    Finally
        query.Connection.Close()
    End Try
End Function
```

This should prevent the method from continuing past the `ExecuteNonQueryAsync()` line until the task returns, so the connection will stay open, but can still run without blocking.

It's also better practice to put the connection and command object in `Using` blocks, and to not worry about exceptions at this level. This is a data access method... separate that from your presentation code. Let the exception bubble up in the calling code, especially in an Async method:

```
Friend Shared Async Function AddMember(member As Object) As Task(Of Integer)
    Using cn AS New SqlConnection(Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Carrel").ConnectionString), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO JSON (CATEGORY,DATA) VALUES ('MEM',@JSONString)", cn)

        query.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@JSONString", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(member)))
        cn.Open()

        Return Await query.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()

    End Using
End Function
```

Just be careful, because the async code could be hiding exceptions from you now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, as Aman Bachas said, you're calling ExecuteNonQueryAsync which will start the operation in the background.  But then your Finally block will execute and close the connection before the execute actually happens.

What you'll need to do is call the non-Async version but then do your own Async so you can close the connection after it's done.

```
    Public Function AddMember(member As Object) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Integer)

        Dim connection = New SqlConnection(Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Carrel").ConnectionString)
        Dim query = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO JSON (CATEGORY,DATA) VALUES ('MEM',@JSONString)", connection)
        Try
            connection.Open()
            query.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@JSONString", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(member)))
            Return Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(Of Integer)(Function()
                                                                         Dim ret = query.ExecuteNonQuery()
                                                                         connection.Close()
                                                                         Return ret
                                                                     End Function)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString())
            Throw
        End Try
    End Function
```

You'll probably want to add some error handling inside the task and clean this up a bit, but that should give you a starting point.

Answer (score -1):

Please replace ExecuteNonQueryAsync() with the ExecuteNonQuery().

Comment: That's not what he wants at all. Notice the return type of the function is a `Task`.